# HTML5 Rich app: a way to deliver printable reports

Tags: javascript, html

HTML5 Rich app.

I need to deliver to a user printable (A4 format) report from the application. So that the user could see it preview version in the app, and then print it.

What alternatives do I have to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are currently doing this at Agency Fusion, and have been looking at some libraries/services like:

- [WickedPDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) (ruby)
- DocRaptor (SaaS with multi-lingual api wrappers)
- Prawn (ruby)

We have decided to go with Wicked PDF and using [css page-break properties](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp)

This way we have control over how the pdf is rendered. The user can then download the PDF as the report, and then send it to the printer if they wish to print it.

Answer (score 3):

There are two completly different approaches:

- Try to create "printable" HTML, deal with all cross-browser issues (I mean the printing-related ones, that go on top of the "usual" ones), lose control over page headers etc.
- Use something, that is "electronic paper" - PDF being the most prominent suspect. There are many libraries to facilitate this approach.

You might be able to infer which version I prefer from my tone.

Comment: Thanks. What is the options to generate PDF files with tables and pictures with JS (I use node.js on server side)?

Comment: Is it possible to draw tables there (or other structured staff)?